# YII active record select only specified fileds

Tags: activerecord, yii

I want to get only specified fields, but when I do this:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $criteria->condition = 't.DeletionMark = 0';
 $criteria->select = 't.Description, address.Description, city.Description';
 $data = WCatalogInternetCounterparties::model()->with('internetCounterpartyAddresses.address.city')->findAll($criteria);
```

Active Record generates query with all fields in select Condition

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using Active Records, you can get only the desired fields with DAO.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('t.Description, address.Description, city.Description')
    ->where('t.DeletionMark = 0')
    ->from('w_catalog_internet_counterparties')
    ->with('internetCounterpartyAddresses.address.city')
    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: You must use `->where(..)` instead `->condition(..)` ... There are no **condition** function in **CDbCommand** class